# Postback pegando dados da base com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, guzzle

Tenho uma base de dados em MYSQL onde um dos campos informa o status de uma determinada transação. Por exemplo: status = aguardando ou status = completa.

Eu quero fazer um cron que de 10 em 10 minutos pegue todos os clientes que estão com o status=completo e quero postar os dados retornados para outra URL, eu vou usar os mesmos dados em outra aplicação. Eu vou usar Guzzle para enviar esses dados, mas ainda não sei como fazer a requisição.

Pra evitar de mandar os dados duplicados, eu tenho a seguinte informação na tabela, processado=0, assim que eu envio o POST e tenho um código 200 de retorno, eu atualizo a informação para processado=1, então a query precisa buscar os dados com status=completo e processado=0

eu imagino que consiga fazer isso com foreach, mas em alguns testes aqui isso não deu certo!